# Grails app resource location in root directory

Tags: grails

So my initial problem was that my static resources were placed to `appName/static/` and what I wanted to do is to place them to just root directory.
I found this: `grails.resources.uri.prefix` property and thought that if I change it to '/' it'll all be fine, but now what happens is that it places the resources to `appName///` instead.

Is there any way to place them into the app root directory?

Comment: Do you want to physically place them on the root for any reason other than accessing them with /resourceName on the browser?

Comment: the whole app is just an addition to someone else's site and the resources on his end are in the root directory (which he doesn't want to change). So in order for me to access them i need those settings changed. Or so I thought.

Comment: I would attempt to achieve this functionality through an UrlMappings rule

Comment: Turns out it wasn't the problem at all it's by design there. Perhaps I was 'digging' in the wrong direction, but thank you all for your input.